# iOS Swift - Best way to compare if a NSDate is between now and x days away

Tags: ios, swift, nsdate

Is there a good way to check if a NSDate is between now and x days away from now?

I mean without filtering the month-day and doing stuff on it manually.

I use swift to develop and am very new in iOS developing.

Comment: You would use the same APIs you would use in Objective-C. There are thousands of examples on this. Date comparison is one of the most asked questions on here.

Comment: Generally you're going to use NSCalendar and NSDateComponents.

Comment: I know how to compare the date I just don't know how to increase the current date by x days without filtering the month-day and doing string operations on it

Comment: See `dateByAddingComponents` or `dateByAddingUnit` of `NSCalendar`.

Comment: Generally you're going to use NSCalendar and NSDateComponents.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you know how to compare two dates you can use dateByAddingUnit to find out the date xDays from today as follow:

edit/update: **Swift 3.x - Swift 4**

```
extension Date {
    func adding(days: Int) -> Date {
        return Calendar.current.date(byAdding: .day, value: days, to: self)!
    }
}
```

---

```
let fiveDaysFromToday = Date().adding(days: 5)  // "Jun 19, 2017 at 5:25 PM"
```

Comment: yes that was what I was looking for. and the extension feature is really great :D